# How to PUT XmlSlurper back to REST with HttpBuilder

Tags: rest, groovy, httpbuilder, xmlslurper, http-put

I'm trying to make GET and then PUT call on XML REST web service.

I do it this way:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7')
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def url = "http://localhost:81"
def pathPrefix = "/api/v1"

def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
def profile = http.request(GET, XML) { req ->
    uri.path = "$pathPrefix/profiles/55"
    response.success = {resp, xml ->
        xml
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(profile) // this is fine!
```

Now i'm going to change and save

```
profile.name = "New Name"

// this is not fine (i have 400 Bad Request)
// because it sends body not in XML
def savedProfile = http.request(PUT, XML) { req ->
    uri.path = "$pathPrefix/profiles/55"
    body = profile
    response.success = {resp, xml ->
        xml
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(savedProfile)
```

When i make PUT request HTTPBuilder do not send XML. It sends string, made of profile.toString().

It it not what i'm expecting.
How to send XmlSlurper object (that i obtained earlier) in PUT request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution.
When i define body configuration value, i have to write

```
body = {
    mkp.yield profile
}
```